# In the sentence, "If n is a prime number then n^2 has three positive factors" why do we have to assume n is a natural number for it to be a statement?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am new to proofs and working through Mathematical Reasoning (version 3) by Ted Sundstrom, and just really want to make sure I am understanding why things are the way they are. In the first chapter he defines a statement to be "a declarative sentence that must have a definite truth value, either true or false but not both". In one of the exercises we have to determine whether or not the sentence qualifies as a statement.

For this question, "If n is a prime number, then n^2 has three positive factors", the author specifies in the answers at the end of the book that the sentence only qualifies as a statement "if we are assuming that n is a prime number means that n is a natural number".

Why is this assumption necessary for the sentence to qualify as a statement? In what scenario would not making this assumption mean that the sentence is not a statement (especially as it is baked into the definition of a prime number that it is a positive natural number, so why is clarifying the assumption necessary?)

Comment: It is always a statement. It is just wrong for, say, $n=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: But wouldn't it not be necessary to even consider a number like sqr 2 when the beginning of the sentence specifies "if n is a prime number"?

Comment: What's the definition according to the book of "prime"?  I can see how a definition *could* be "$n$ is prime of it's has no natural factors other that $1$ and itself".  In which case any non integer is prime as a non-integer will have no natural factors at all. ($a$ is a factor of $n$ if and only if there is an integer $k$ so that $ak=n$.  If $a$ is a natural number then $n =ak\in\mathbb Z$.  So any non-integer has no natural factors.)

Comment: Earlier he defines prime as "a positive integer greater than 1 whose only positive factors are 1 and itself"... so it seems making the assumption of n being a natural number is not necessary.

Comment: I think you understand the text better than Sunderson is giving credit the average student to understand.  He states "For example, the
equation $2x +5 = 10$ is not a statement since we do not know what $x$ represents".  So the sentence "$n^2$ has three positive factors" is not a sentence.  But "whenever $n$ is a prime number, $n^2$ has three positive factors" is.  I *guess* he is trying to emphasis that for "if $n$ is prime, then..." is only a statement when specifically indicate $n$ is prime (which we *do*).  It's not that well worded.  I'll keep reading and see if I get any insight.

Comment: Okay.... on further reading... "If $n$ is prime then $n^2$ has $3$ positive factors" is a conditional statement and it's truth is determined but the truth of the hypothesis.  But the argument (simple though it is) is not direct we must determine that the hypothesis "$n$ is a prime number" implies another condition "$n$ is a natural number" (it does... but it isn't *explicitely* stated. So the truth is dependent upon whether we can make that conclusion (we can of course) but in determining whether sent are statements *without* determining truth could be implied we can't follow arguments either.

Comment: Okay so if I am understanding, perhaps you are implying that we must know that n being a prime number implies that n is a natural number to determine whether or not the sentence can be definitively determined to be true or false but not both (as per the definition of "statement")?

Answer (score 1):

Without a quantifier, $n$ is unbound. A statement can only have bound variables. The author is merely pointing out the implied "For every natural number $n$" at the start of the statement.

Comment: Isn't saying "if n is a prime number" essentially bounding the numbers that n can be already to positive natural numbers though?

Comment: "Isn't saying "if n is a prime number" essentially bounding the numbers that n can be already to positive natural numbers though?"  Is it?  It's *your* book.  How does it define "prime"?